# Writing an mp4 video using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video

I want to capture video from a webcam and save it to an mp4 file using opencv. I found example code on stackoverflow (below) that works great. The only hitch is that I'm trying to save it as mp4, not avi. Part of what I don't get is that the 'XVID' argument passed to the FOURCC writer is supposed to be, I think, an mp4 codec (from [this link](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)). If I change the filename to 'output.mp4' it tells me that the tag is invalid, so I have to believe that the XVID codec is actually making an avi file. Is this a stupid question? How do I write to an mp4?

I have found links showing how to convert an avi to an mp4 after the fact but that seems inefficient. Seems like I should be able to do it during the initial write.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try using -> fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'H264')

Comment: You will need ffmpeg though

Comment: Try with CV_FOURCC('m', 'p', '4', 'v'). Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28904970/4481702

Comment: @Ha Dang: Nope. That example does exactly the same thing that I'm seeing. The file is still saved as an avi.

Comment: Do you change the output filename to .mp4 extention or not? How do you know it's still saved as avi?

Answer (score 106):

This worked for me.

```
self._name = name + '.mp4'
self._cap = VideoCapture(0)
self._fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
self._out = VideoWriter(self._name, self._fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

Comment: It's been two years! You hadn't expected this upvote, huh?  :P I was using H264 to write to an mp4 file. It created laggy videos upon seeking, this suggestion helped me. MP4V codec solved the issue!   :)

Comment: @varun ha no didnt see it coming :) .. glad it helped you bud.

Comment: @10SecTom does this require ffmpeg to be present ?

Comment: @AkashGoyal its been a while since I played with this stuff. I believe it worked with h264. I had to install openh264.  http://www.openh264.org/faq.html

Comment: It is not working, and says the below error: `OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'`

Comment: @Bahramdun Adil its been so long since I played with this stuff and was not an expert, to begin with.  I did a quick google of your error (which does look familiar) and found a good few posts citing the same issue. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Sorry if it is not related, but can we apply it to opencv c++ as well?

Comment: not sure of the C++ API but I imagine the translation should be similar

Comment: @BahramdunAdil the name of the output file must end with `.mp4`, that's why you are having that error

Comment: I had error codec id 12 instead of @BahramdunAdil 's 13 and changing the CODEC to `*'mp4v'` from to `*'MP4V'` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 25):

What worked for me was to make sure the input 'frame' size is equal to output video's size (in this case, (680, 480) ).

http://answers.opencv.org/question/27902/how-to-record-video-using-opencv-and-python/

Here is my working code (Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: I installed openh264 as suggested by @10SecTom but I'm not sure if that was relevant to the problem.

Just in case:

```
brew install openh264
```

Answer (score 18):

There are some things to change in your code:

1. Change the name of your output to 'output.mp4' (change to .mp4)
2. I had the the same issues that people have in the comments, so I changed the fourcc to `0x7634706d`: `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',0x7634706d , 20.0, (640,480))`

Comment: `0x7634706d` is the same as `mp4v` (lowercase) using fourcc

Answer (score 13):

This is the [default code](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) given to save a video captured by camera

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For about two minutes of a clip captured that `FULL HD`

Using

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(3,1920)
cap.set(4,1080)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (1920,1080))
```

The file saved was more than `150MB`

Then had to use `ffmpeg` to reduce the size of the file saved, between `30MB` to `60MB` based on the quality of the video that is required changed using `crf` lower the crf better the quality of the video and larger the file size generated. You can also change the format `avi`,`mp4`,`mkv`,etc

Then i found [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/)

Here a code to save `numpy array` of each frame as video using `ffmpeg-python`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import ffmpeg

def save_video(cap,saving_file_name,fps=33.0):

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            i_width,i_height = frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]
            break

    process = (
    ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:',format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24',s='{}x{}'.format(i_width,i_height))
        .output(saved_video_file_name,pix_fmt='yuv420p',vcodec='libx264',r=fps,crf=37)
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )

    return process

if __name__=='__main__':

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    cap.set(3,1920)
    cap.set(4,1080)
    saved_video_file_name = 'output.avi'
    process = save_video(cap,saved_video_file_name)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
            process.stdin.write(
                cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    .astype(np.uint8)
                    .tobytes()
                    )

            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                process.stdin.close()
                process.wait()
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
        else:
            process.stdin.close()
            process.wait()
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: 'For about two minutes of a clip captured that FULL HD' where did you specify 2 minutes in the code?

Answer (score 6):

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`

'mp4v' returns no errors unlike 'MP4V' which is defined inside fourcc

for the error:

> "OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id
> 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)' OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to
> use tag 0x00000020/' ???'"

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, I added images.sort() to keep the sequence order:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

image_folder = 'data-set-race-01'
video_file = 'race-01.mp4'
image_size = (160, 120)
fps = 24

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
images.sort()

out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), fps, image_size)

img_array = []
for filename in images:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, filename))
    img_array.append(img)
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone whoe still struggle with the problem. According [this article](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video) I used this sample and it works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So I had to use `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')` codec. Tested with OpenCV 3.4.3 compiled from sources.

Comment: Instructions on how to compile opencv here https://www.swiftlane.com/eng/generating-mp4s-using-opencv-python-with-the-avc1-codec

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who's looking for most convenient and robust way of writing MP4 files with OpenCV or FFmpeg, can see my state-of-the-art [VidGear](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/) Video-Processing Python library's [WriteGear API](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/introduction/) that works with both [OpenCV backend](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/non_compression/overview/) and [FFmpeg backend](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/overview/) and even [supports GPU encoders](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/usage/#using-compression-mode-with-hardware-encoders). Here's an example to encode with H264 encoder in WriteGear with FFmpeg backend:

```
# import required libraries
from vidgear.gears import WriteGear
import cv2

# define suitable (Codec,CRF,preset) FFmpeg parameters for writer
output_params = {"-vcodec":"libx264", "-crf": 0, "-preset": "fast"}

# Open suitable video stream, such as webcam on first index(i.e. 0)
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

# Define writer with defined parameters and suitable output filename for e.g. `Output.mp4`
writer = WriteGear(output_filename = 'Output.mp4', logging = True, **output_params)

# loop over
while True:

    # read frames from stream
    (grabbed, frame) = stream.read()

    # check for frame if not grabbed
    if not grabbed:
      break

    # {do something with the frame here}
    # lets convert frame to gray for this example
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # write gray frame to writer
    writer.write(gray)

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Gray Frame", gray)

    # check for 'q' key if pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# safely close video stream
stream.release()

# safely close writer
writer.close()
```

- Source: https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear
- Docs:
  https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/
- More FFmpeg backend examples:https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/usage/
- OpenCV backend examples:
  https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/gears/writegear/non_compression/usage/

Comment: As to the case of OpenCV as a backend: since OpenCV's video writer is itself [a wrapper](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ad59c61d8881ba2b2da22cff5487465b5) around ffmpeg and other libraries as per the OS platform, I wonder whether there are really particular advantages to using this library with OpenCV as its backend compared to using OpenCV itself. Happy to learn.

Comment: Yes, it not only provides direct access to OpenCV writer in case of OpenCV backend but also automatically handles output file paths, [simplifies assigning FOURCC Codecs](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/non_compression/params/#supported-fourcc-codecs) names and handles any error while encoding files.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV documentation is not very rich with regard to the VideoWriter, however I managed to get it working in the following way (by looking at the stacktrace):

```
import cv2

HEIGHT = 480
WIDTH = 640
FPS = 30.0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_ANY)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, FPS)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB , 1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 100)


cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

# output parameters such as fps and size can be changed
output = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", fourcc, FPS, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

while True:
    if cap.isOpened():
        (ret, frame) = cap.read()
        if ret:
            output.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break

output.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The stacktrace error was:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 12 and 
format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
```

Unfortunately, it is difficult to find a list of the official codecs used by OpenCV, or at least I could not find them. In any case, it appears that you have to enter the codec 'mp4v' written in lower case.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d01/group__videoio__c.html#gac005718f121379beffdbdbfb44f2646a

One important thing I noticed is that the aspect ratio of the frame and the output video must be the same, which is why I use two variables for height and width. If these two are different, the file is created, but the frames are not saved (you always end up with a 1KB mp4 file). To avoid any problems you could do the same for FPS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem such as `OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)' OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'`  maybe that your output video size is not the same as original video. You can look over the frame size of video first.

Comment: No, that problem is because the video codec doesn't match with the output's filename. If u are using `MP4V`, the output file must end with `.mp4`. Same way with `XVID`  output filename should end with `.avi`

Comment: I went down this deep dive and recorded my solution in this blog post if that helps https://www.swiftlane.com/eng/generating-mp4s-using-opencv-python-with-the-avc1-codec

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the codec to `'mp4v'` (**lowercase**). If set in uppercase, an error would be thrown saying that *is not supported*, suggesting to use lowercase instead: `OpenCV:`[`FFMPEG`](http://ffmpeg.org/)`:fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'`. You may also want to have a look at the documentation of [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html), as well as the examples given [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html). Also, please make sure your output video's size is equal to  your input `frame` size (the below takes care of this, using the dimensions of the `VideoCapture` object).

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, fps, (int(w),int(h)))
```

You can get the entire list of codecs available for `mp4`, etc., by setting `fourcc=-1`. For instance:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', -1, fps, (int(w),int(h)))
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 (2023) `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

OS: **Windows 11**

Python: **3.12.0**

OpenCV: **4.9.0.80**

```
import cv2

vid_source_path = 0     # Path to video source, 0 for webcam
# vid_source_path = 'input_vi.mp4'     # Path to video source, 0 for webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_source_path)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video Source.")
    exit()


# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
ret = False
while not ret:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to grab the first frame from the video source, Trying again...")
    else:
        print(f'Height: {frame.shape[0]}, Width: {frame.shape[1]}')

height, width = frame.shape[:2]

# TO save the video in AVI format
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')  # You can change the codec if needed
# out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_vid.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))


# To save the video in MP4 format
# Note: 'X264' might not work on some systems, 'MP4V' or 'AVC1' can be alternatives.
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_vid.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))



while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret != True:
        break

    # write the frame
    out.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -2):

just change the codec to `"DIVX"`. This codec works with all formats.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
```

i hope this works for you!